# How to Sort an Appended List In an if Statement in Python?

Tags: python, list, if-statement, append

I have these blocks of codes here.

When you enter an input, the input is supposed to be sorted alphabetically to the existing list.

However, my input keeps going to the bottom of the list. I have been at this for 2 hours and can't even remember anymore what I have tried. My apologies. This is my first post here. Below are the codes:

```
names = ['Anna', 'Faizal', 'Fylvia', 'Karl', 'Maria', 'Matt']
for i in names:
    print(i)

print('Enter a new name')      
newNames = input()

if newNames == names.append(newNames) == newList:
    newList.sort()
    print(newList)
    
else:
    newNames == ' '
    print('\n'.join(names))
```

Comment: `names.append(newNames)` doesn't return anything, so the `==` comparison will never succeed.

Comment: Where do you define `newList`?

Comment: I don't understand what you're trying to do in that `if` statement.

Answer (score 4):

There's lots of confusing, unnecessary code. Just append the new name to the list and then sort it.

```
names = ['Anna', 'Faizal', 'Fylvia', 'Karl', 'Maria', 'Matt']
print('\n'.join(names))

newname = input('Enter a new name: ')
names.append(newname)
names.sort()
print('\n'.join(names))
```

Comment: Thanks very much, Barmar! You have clarified my question and I understand the codes can be cleaner now! That was super helpful!